# Heat Equation - PDE

Tags: pde, finite-difference, python, parabolic-pde

I'm trying to model the Black-Scholes Equation (transformed into a heat equation) using method of lines in Python.

The transformed formula is basically

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + (k-1)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - ku
\end{equation*}

where $k$ is a constant and with initial condition

\begin{equation*}
u(x,0) = \max(e^x - 1, 0)
\end{equation*}

and boundary conditions

\begin{equation*}
u(a,t) = \alpha \hspace{35pt} u(b,t) = \beta
\end{equation*}

This is python implementation of the method of lines for the above equation should match the results  [in the matlab code here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//henry/reports/talks.d/t09talks.d/09waterloomatlab.d/mfileshigham.d/bs.m). I can't seem to find where I went wrong. Any insight on the Python code would be really helpful.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fftpack import diff as psdiff

N = 40
r = 0.065;
sigma = 0.8;
k = float(0.5*sigma**2);
a = np.log(float(2)/5)
b = np.log(float(7)/5)
t0 = 0;
tf = 5;

x = np.linspace(a, b, N);
xmesh = np.max(np.exp(a)-1,0)*np.ones(x.shape)

def odefunc(u, t):
    dudt = np.zeros(xmesh.shape)

    #boundary conditions
    dudt[0] = u[0]
    dudt[-1] = (7 - 5*np.exp(-k*t))/5 

    #step size
    h = b/(N-1)

    for i in range(1, N-1):
        dudt[i] = ((u[i + 1] - 2*u[i] + u[i - 1]) / h**2) + (k-1)*((u[i] - u[i-1]) / h) - (k*u[i])
    return dudt

tspan = np.linspace(t0, tf, 20);
sol = odeint(odefunc, xmesh, tspan)

for i in range(0, len(tspan), 5):
    plt.plot(xmesh, sol[i], label='t={0:1.2f}'.format(tspan[i]))

# put legend outside the figure
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.xlabel('X position')
plt.ylabel('Temperature')

# adjust figure edges so the legend is in the figure
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.89, right=0.77)
plt.savefig('pde.png')

# Make a 3d figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

SX, ST = np.meshgrid(xmesh, tspan)
ax.plot_surface(SX, ST, sol, cmap='jet')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('t')
ax.set_zlabel('u')
ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=100) # adjust view so it is easy to see
plt.savefig('pde-transient-heat-3d.png')
```

[image: 3d Plot]

The plot, I believe should look like the following
[image: plot]

Comment: Can you state more clearly what is your question?

Comment: I don't think that its all that clear what you are asking. What should the solution look like? I think your plotting is confusing and I am not really sure what the plot should look like on such a narrow range of x. I know Black-Scholes is for option pricing but maybe you could expand on what x and u represent here and choose a better plot (maybe a 2d plot with multiple solutions for each time instead of the 3d plot)? For all I know your plot my be correct and thus there is no question here.

Comment: oops never mind it looks like nicoguaro has been able to find the solution to your problem after all =).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question. My python MOL implementation is supposed to match the matlab code for the black-scholes equation. @nicoguaro seems to have pointed out the bug in my code (thanks, by the way!). It still doesn't match the matlab results; I think the problem now is in the variables themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just plot the wrong thing. The variable `xmesh` is the initial condition, not the value of `x` (in your particular case it is constant -0.6). But you don't have the same parameters in your Python and Matlab codes, you are also applying badly your initial conditions.

See here the corrected code (please read it carefully):

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def odefunc(u, t):
    dudt = np.zeros(x0.shape)

    #boundary conditions
    dudt[0] = u[0]
    dudt[-1] = (7 - 5*np.exp(-k*t))/5 

    #step size
    h = b/(N-1)

    for i in range(1, N-1):
        dudt[i] = (u[i + 1] - 2*u[i] + u[i - 1]) / h**2 +\
                   (k-1)*(u[i] - u[i-1]) / h - k*u[i]
    return dudt


N = 40
r = 0.065;
sigma = 0.8;
k = r/sigma**2
a = np.log(2/5)
b = np.log(7/5)
t0 = 0
tf = 5

x = np.linspace(a, b, N);
x0 = np.exp(x) - 1
x0[x0 < 0] = 0

tspan = np.linspace(t0, tf, 20);
sol = odeint(odefunc, x0, tspan)


#%% Make a 3d figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

SX, ST = np.meshgrid(x, tspan)
ax.plot_surface(SX, ST, sol, cmap='YlGnBu_r',
                rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('t')
ax.set_zlabel('u')
ax.view_init(elev=30, azim=-115)
plt.savefig('pde-transient-heat-3d.png')
plt.show()
```

If you plot against `x`, you obtain this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Trying it in matlab with the pdepe function (see [code here](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//henry/reports/talks.d/t09talks.d/09waterloomatlab.d/mfileshigham.d/bs.m)) seems to produce a different result however. Any idea on why that would be?

Comment: Both codes were note equivalent, you need to pay more attention to those details.

Comment: Thanks! In your code, I believe xmesh should be x or x0. But besides that, thanks so much! :)